# How to retrieve all docs from couchdb and convert it as CSV using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, couchdb

I need to retrieve all docs with the specified field from couchdb, but only getting result from one document. But when I print it, all docs are showing

```
for item in db.view('_all_docs'):
    doc = item.doc
    _id = item['id']

    f = open('retrieve.csv', 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([_id])
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Do you mean you want to stop after reading the first document from the database?

Comment: My problem is, i need to get "all documents" from the database but when i run that code, im only getting one result . Also, when i print the _id ; print(_id), im getting all the documents, but when converting it to csv, the output is only one ID

Comment: Just curious, why are you opening the file at each iteration of the loop? Is it possible to open the file once before the loop and close it once after the loop?

Comment: Yes it's possible . i modified my code and put the open file outside my loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get all , the open file needs to be outside the loop

```
f = open('retrieve.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)
for item in db.view('_all_docs'):
    doc = item.doc
    _id = item['id']
    writer.writerow([_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn a CouchDB dataset into a CSV you could either use the CouchDB Show function if you just need to do it for one single document or the CouchDB List function if you need to do combine multiple documents.

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.2/ddocs/ddocs.html#show-functions

http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/show.html

http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html